# comparing data in list of objects

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a JSON which returning a duplicate object if it has a different value for one of the attributes, for example:

```
   {
    "nid": "41",
    "news_title": "title",
    "body": "body",
    "news_image": "img1.JPG",
},
{
    "nid": "41",
    "news_title": "title",
    "body": "body",
    "news_image": "img2.JPG",
},
```

both of them are the same node with ID 41 and the other data are duplicated other than the unique which is news_image

The class of the object is:

```
  String nid;
  String newsTitle;
  String body;
  String newsImage;
  List<String> newsImgs;
```

And am parsing it like this:

```
 List<News> newsdata = (jsonResponse as List).map((i) => new News.fromJson(i));
```

Everything is fine till now .. but i have another list:

```
List<News> newsList = <News>[];
```

Where i want to add the images of the same news with the same nid to the list newsImgs and then add it to the newsList.. so i wont have duplicated news with the same nid and all of the images of the same news will be in one list

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this list..
Set store only unique value..

```
  Set<News> newsList= new Set();
newsList.addAll(newsdata);
```

Comment: but here i didn't store the images in one array?

Comment: you want store only image url.

Comment: in my example you can see that the single have to different images .. i want to store those images in newsImgs list and then add the news object to the list